# angular cli 6 custom options for build (environment variables)

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

**Well, I don't like to have environment variables on version control because I want to be able to configure the application without deploying the app all over again.**

I have one question. How can I add in angular cli 6 custom option from ng build command?
For example I wath to: ng build --api-url="http:/my-url.com"
In other words, how can I set environment variables?

Comment: Hi, make use of the environment files inside the directory environments.

Comment: I don't have time to make a formal answer but, since Angular is not aware of process.env you might want to try configuring a .env file and grab specs from that. As shown in this medium article: https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659

Comment: Michael Sorensen, thank you. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might help you.

For my own project, I have 4 environment files,

1. environment.ts (for my localhost)
2. environment.dev.ts (for my dev testing server)
3. environment.staging.ts (for my staging test server)
4. environment.prod.ts (for my project's production server)

All 4 files have different API URLs (base URL for my project's API calls), so I need a custom build for each environment.

Now I believe your situation is more or less the same, so I'd suggest you create different environment files.

Then in your `angular.json` file, you need to define these configurations as follows:

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              ...
              ...
              ...
              ...
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              ...
              ...
              ...
              ...
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              ...
              ...
              ...
              ...
            }
          }
```

After defining all the configurations, all you need to do is run the ng build command with the configuration option.

- For dev `ng build --configuration=dev`
- For staging `ng build --configuration=staging`
- For production `ng build --configuration=production`

And that's it. Now your builds would use the proper environment files.